# How to make a sentinel value in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

The following example, in Python, may help illustrate what I mean by a "sentinel value":

```
SENTINEL = object()
def foo(opt=SENTINEL):
    if opt is SENTINEL:
        opt = make_me_fresh_default_opt_please()
    # etc
```

In the snippet above the variable `SENTINEL` is initialized to a brand new "nonce" object, one that has, as it were, no content, and no conceivable meaning anywhere else outside the file where it is defined.  `foo` is a function that takes an optional argument, `opt`.  The constant `SENTINEL` is used by `foo` for *one thing and one thing only*: to test the condition of being called with no arguments.  This is done with `if opt is SENTINEL`.

To see why one would want such a cheap, "nonce" constant like `SENTINEL`, contrast the snippet above with one that uses a standard Python value (`None`) to test the no-argument condition:

```
def foo2(opt=None):
    if opt is None:
        opt = make_me_fresh_default_opt_please()
    # etc
```

This function `foo2` cannot distinguish between the two calls below<sup>1</sup>:

```
foo2()
foo2(None)
```

So, in sum, by "sentinel" here I mean a constant value that is unknown to the rest of the code, and whose only purpose is to serve as the basis for a boolean test for some condition.

Is there a similarly simple way to generate such a sentinel constant in MATLAB?

EDIT: I want to stress that my question is strictly about how to create a sentinel, leaving open the issue of the purpose to which such sentinel would be used.  I provided a concrete and plausible example of why one may want such a sentinel constant, in part to make sure that readers of the post would know what I meant by the word "sentinel".  In this example, the sentinel *just happens* to be used to test for a "no argument passed" condition, but there are countless other possible conditions that one may want to test using a sentinel value.  So, this question is, emphatically, not about testing for a "no argument passed" condition, but about the problem of generating sentinel constants, in general.

EDIT2: based on Notlikethat's and Bas Swinckels's answers:

```
function y = foo(varargin)
    p = inputParser;
    p.addParameter('Opt', @DEFAULT);
    p.parse(varargin{:});

    opt = p.Results.Opt;
    if DEFAULT(opt)
        opt = rand();
    end

    y = opt;
    % etc
end

function its_me = DEFAULT(opt)
    its_me = isequal(opt, @DEFAULT);
end

%{
>> foo('Opt', 3)
ans =
     3
>> foo()
ans =
    0.9134
>> foo
ans =
    0.6324
%}
```

OK, that's maybe too-cute-by-half.  The code is both simpler and clearer if it stays closer to Notlikethat's original suggestion (note that `make_sentinel` below is a free-standing function):

```
% foo.m
function y = foo(varargin)
    DEFAULT = make_sentinel();
    p = inputParser;
    p.addParameter('Opt', DEFAULT);
    p.parse(varargin{:});

    opt = p.Results.Opt;
    if isequal(opt, DEFAULT)
        opt = rand();
    end

    y = opt;
    % etc
end

% make_sentinel.m
function sentinel = make_sentinel()
    sentinel = ...
       @() 'qqqxyz_lalala_the_user_would_be_a_moron_to_use_this_function';
    % or, more conventionally,
    % sentinel = @() 0;
end


>> foo('Opt', 6)
ans =
     6
>> foo()
ans =
    0.9575
>> foo
ans =
    0.9649
```

And to show that the sentinels produced by `make_sentinel` are indeed unique (and that perversity won't pay):

```
>> foo('Opt', make_sentinel())
ans = 
    @()'qqqxyz_lalala_the_user_would_be_a_moron_to_use_this_function'
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Of course, the `foo` defined earlier cannot distinguish between `foo()` and `foo(SENTINEL)`, but, AFAIC, a call like the latter falls within the category of "perverse programming" (since it requires the calling code to "go out of its way" to subvert the called code's intentions), and I don't worry about such perversities.  In contrast, the `foo2(None)` example shown earlier illustrates a situation that could happen easily in the course of routine programming, especially when the actual source code for it is something like `foo(some_variable)`, and `some_variable` unintendedly ends up holding the standard Python value `None`.</sub>

Comment: So to clarify, you aren't actually looking for default value behavior, you're looking to create a sentinel that will be used for some entirely different purpose?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I've added an EDIT to my post that hopefully clarifies what I'm after.

Comment: Well, you do not have a "concrete and plausible example" of what a sentinel value could be used for, because MATLAB does not allow default-valued arguments, only optional ones.  To detect missing argument, you must use `nargin`, a sentinel value won't work for that concrete case.

Comment: @BenVoigt: there are other ways besides `nargin` to detect missing arguments.  See docs for `inputParser`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: besides, my "concrete and plausible example" was in Python (a language I'm 1000x more familiar with than I am with MATLAB), and it is indeed both concrete and plausible in that language.  The purpose of the example was to clarify what I meant by the word "sentinel", not to make a statement about MATLAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be pretty much the direct equivalent:

```
function y = foo(opt)
    %default argument
    if nargin<1
        opt = @SENTINEL;
    end

    %actual check
    if isequal(opt, @SENTINEL)
        opt = make_me_fresh_default_opt_please()
    end

    % etc
end

function SENTINEL  % private function in the same file
end
```

Admittedly not *quite* as simple, but that's as much down to Matlab syntax as anything else.

You could probably also cheat a bit and base it on *exactly* the same approach:

```
SENTINEL = java.lang.Object;
% etc...
```

Sacrificing guaranteed uniqueness for even more simplicity, `tempname` is an easy way to generate a string that's unlikely to collide with valid data (especially if valid data *isn't* strings...)

Comment: Thanks!  I like your first idea best, but when I tried it, I got an error, saying that `eq` is not defined for function handles.  Happily, however, `isequal` works, and as a bonus, it obviates the need for the `isa` test.  (See EDIT2 in my post.)

Comment: @kjo Good catch, thanks. Clearly this is one of those implementation details where Octave subtly differs. I miss proper Matlab...

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "foolproof" way of determining within a function call that no arguments were passed in, then using `nargin` is the idiomatic MATLAB way to do that.

Within a function body, calling `nargin` will return the number of arguments passed to your function.  So you could write code like...

```
function foo(a, b)
    switch nargin
        case 0
            % Handle the no-argument case...
        case 1
            % Handle the one-argument case...
        otherwise
            % All arguments supplied...
    end
    % Other code here...
end
```

See [the MATLAB documentation for nargin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) for more information.

Comment: No, my question is precisely as I asked it: I'm looking for a way to produce a sentinel in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have a unique sentinel value, you could create your own sentinel class. But I guess that in any realistic context, it should always be trivial to find some standard number/cell/struct/string that cannot be produced by any function or user input. This could be as simple as

```
SENTINEL  = 'qqqxyz_lalala_the_user_would_be_a_moron_to_use_this_string';
```

Users that would use this value clearly fall under your definition of 'perverse programming'. Testing if a variable is the sentinel or not can be done with this function:

```
issentinel = @(var) ischar(var) && strcmp(var, SENTINEL)
```

Note also the [inputParser](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparserclass.html) class, which lets you define default values for missing arguments, which might reduce the need for sentinel values.

Comment: +1 just for the proposed sentinel, even if it is somewhat...--let us say-- *unconventional*.

Comment: Also, although I don't have much experience at all with `inputParser`, if I understand its documentation correctly, then your statement about it holds only in cases when a true default value can be specified in advance, which is not always the case.  The value to use if the user doesn't provide one may need to be determined dynamically (i.e. "at run time"), e.g., by fetching it from a remote source, etc. In such situations, the so-called "default" given to `inputParser` would not really be a default value, but in fact a sentinel signaling the "no argument passed" condition.  (See my EDIT2.)

Comment: I stand corrected regarding `inputParser`: upon further study I discovered the `UsingDefaults` property, which, as you suggested, does obviate the need to use sentinels to detect the "no argument passed" condition.